# Bootstrap 3 - Issue with right margins

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Can someone tell me why I have a slight margin to the right on this site?  There should be no way to scroll horizontally, regardless of the size of the browser.

I'm not sure if it's something I've done in the way I'm mixing rows and columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overriding the bootstrap styles on line 65 of extendStyles.css:

```
.container-fluid {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

If you remove that, your problem will be fixed. Bootstrap requires left and right padding of 15px on the container to offset the negative left and right margins on the rows.

Comment: Now I have an issue with certain rows not spanning the entire width of the browser.  <div class="row hidden-sm hidden-xs" id="slide2"> </div> for example.

Comment: @user1110562 there you need to remove `width: 100%`, `display: inline-block`, and `margin: 0` from `#slide2`. Try to avoid overriding bootstrap styles on things like containers, rows, and columns and you will have a much easier time. Usually those styles are there for a reason to make the grid system work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Steve Sanders.  I'm still new to bootstrap and sometimes forget it takes care of a lot of housekeeping for you.

Comment: @user1110562 no worries, glad to help. Site looks great by the way!